# How to implement two tyoe of authentication in apache

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, adfs, shibboleth

I have already implemented with shibboleth on apache an adfs authentication with SAML2.

Now i need to add a second authentication type with OAUTH2.

How to achieve this solution for use both authentication ?

Comment: you should google it and figure it out before asking others to do your work for you. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you asking how to implement this on apache or on ADFS?